# Faça um programa que leia um número menor que 1000 e mostre a unidade, centena e dezena. Obs: O programa não pode entradas que não sejam números

Tags: python, while

Boa noite a todos, estou mais de 3 dias tentando resolver esse questão. Porém, o programa não executa o código inserido dentro do while (Logo após a pessoa colocar o número, o programa já pula para a linha depois dos códigos do while).

Eis aqui o código:

N_Int = int (input ('Digite um número menor que 1000:'))

while N_Int is (bool, float, str) or N_Int >= 1000:

NII = int (input ('Digite novamente:'))

```
if len (str (N_Int or NII)) == 3:
    Dezena_N = N_Int or NII [0:1]
    Centena_N = N_Int or NII [1:2]
    Unidade_N = N_Int or NII [2:3]
    print (f'O número {N_Int or NII} tem {Dezena_N} dezenas, {Centena_N} centenas e {Unidade_N} unidades.')
if len (str (N_Int or NII)) == 2:
    Dezena_N = N_Int or NII [0:1]
    Centena_N = N_Int or NII [1:2]
    print (f'O número {N_Int or NII} tem {Dezena_N} dezenas e {Centena_N} centenas.')
if len (str (N_Int or NII)) == 2:
    Dezena_N = N_Int or NII [0:1]
    print (f'O número {N_Int or NII} tem {Dezena_N} dezenas.')
```

print('Fim do programa!')

Comment: A indentação do seu código está inconsistente, e em Python isso pode quebrar seu programa. Replique aqui a indentação exata do seu código.

Comment: https://ideone.com/ifFjwU

Answer (score -2):

Uma solução escalável seria:

```
numero=int(input("Digite um numero:"))
while numero>=1000:
  print("O numero precisa ser menor que mil")
  numero=int(input("Digite um numero:"))
numero=str(numero)
numero=numero[::-1]
lista=["unidade","dezena","centena"]
for i, num in enumerate(numero):
  print(num+" é "+lista[i])
print("Fim do programa")
```

[::-1] serve para inverter a ordem dos algarismos.